# How to get string from a long string?

Tags: nsstring

I have a string like this:

```
NSString *aString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:"********************Documents/image%@.jpg",aNumber];
```

I want to get "Documents/image%@.jpg" out of the string?

What can I do? I want to use "substringFromIndex" but I don't know the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rangeOfString` to find the index of "Documents...".
[NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a)

And then use that with 'substringFromIndex' to get the substring you want.
For example:

```
[astring substringFromIndex:[aString rangeOfString:@"Documents"].location]
```

You should add error checking to make sure that the range returned by the 'rangeOfString' method is good.